# How could I import a existent users table into another one with different structure?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, import

suppose I have a users table but with different structure, how could I import all the data into another one?

lets say I have:

```
users:
- id
- name
- created_at
- updated_at
```

and another one already populated with:

```
users:
- id
- login
- created_at
- updated_at
```

its just a sample to easy visualization.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at insert into select

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Thanks but Pentium10 deserved accepted answer more than me. I just give you a link :)

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO users2 
            (LOGIN, 
             created_at, 
             updated_at) 
SELECT name, 
       created_at, 
       updated_at 
FROM   users1
```